# Problem in Variogram Plot

Tags: r, variogram

I tried to plot Variogram by this code from `gstat` packages:

```
v <- variogram(log(zinc) ~ 1, meuse)
plot(v)
```

and here is the output:
[image]

But I want to add line to point (draw variogram line).

How I can add line to the plot?

Comment: Look at chapter 5 Variograms in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/gstat.pdf.

Comment: You need to look at the plot function and it's related arguments. In this case you would just use: plot(v, type = "l") or if you want both line and point type = "b "

Comment: @John Barça and PolyGeo, you should read something about the package `gstat` related to the R-programming language before you declare it as a non GIS topic. Cite `gstat`: Spatial and Spatio-Temporal Geostatistical Modelling, Prediction and Simulation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/index.html